# How to install RestFB plugin in Play Framework 2

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, restfb

I'm using Play Framework 2.1.3 and want to use RestFB to work with Facebook Graph API but I can't get it installed properly. Here is my Build.scala

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  "com.restfb"    %% "restfb" % "1.6.12"
)

val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
  resolvers += Resolver.url("restfb (release)", url("http://revetkn.github.com/restfb/repo/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
  resolvers += Resolver.url("restfb (snapshot)", url("http://revetkn.github.com/restfb/repo/snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
)
```

After this I run `play update` but it returns:

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.restfb#restfb_2.10;1.6.12: not found
```

I appreciate if anyone managed to install it properly kindly give me some hints/instructions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/revetkn/restfb:

> RestFB is a pure Java Facebook Graph API and Old REST API client with
>   no external dependencies.

So gather the library with:

```
"com.restfb"    % "restfb" % "1.6.12"
```

[The %% is just used for Scala libraries.](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies.html)